# Separable Hilbert space having uncountable orthonormal set.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose we have a separable Hilbert space $H$ having a countable orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$. How do I show that any orthonormal set of vectors has to be at most countable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a ONS, you have
$$\| e_i - e_j \| = \sqrt{2}$$
for $i \ne j$. Since $H$ is separable, you have that $I$ is at most countable.